Does the Planck length imply space is finite?
How true is the following line of logic?

The existence of the Planck length means space is granular
Therefore the "grains" are countable (i.e. finite in number or countably infinite)
In a quantum state space involving position, the possible positions are represented by orthonormal basis elements of a Hilbert space (complete inner product vector space)
If space is granular then these basis element are countable.
A Hilbert space's orthonormal basis is either finite or uncountably infinite but cannot be countably infinite.
Therefore space is finite.

(and the same for Planck time).

Last I checked $\mathbb{R}^{3,1}$ is not a countably-finite set of four-vectors even with arbitrary restrictions imposed on it. This proof is otherwise decent but 2. does not follow directly from 1. You cannot assign a single counting number to each event in spacetime (which is unbounded as far as can be told) so 2. is false.

@controlgroup Thanks for feedback

If the grains overlap, they can be uncountable.

We know that space is expanding. I don't think it makes sense that this would mean that each grain of space is expanding, but rather that the number of grains is increasing. So it would not be countable because it is always increasing

The existence of Planck length and Planck time does not imply that either is finite. Everybody harbours some suspicion that spacetime is finite, but nobody has ever made a theory with finite spacetime quanta and managed to come out with a tolerable theory, and that is definitely not for a lack of trying. Every attempt so far ended up with false predictions.

@foolishmuse Note that there are already an infinite number of grains because space is flat at large scales and thus unbounded: $\infty+1$ does not make sense. Letting the grains expand is pretty much how the widely-accepted FLRW metric works.

1 is not generally accepted. The Planck scale is where quantum gravity becomes relevant, not a smallest possible length.
